# Obfuscating socket stream

Tags: sockets

Just a quick question, I was reading some TOR research, and noticed someone made a patch that makes all network communication look like plaintext (well to heuristics looking for TOR traffic indicators; to a human it still looks like gibberish)

I was wondering is it feasible to do the opposite across a Python socket? Make encrypted plaintext look like semi-legitimate HTML (to a script looking for HTML).

If so, does anyone have any ideas/tips on how I could go about this? I have yet to think of an intelligent way I could go about this...

Also as its encypted plaintext thinking it would it be easier to make it look like https traffic??

Comment: XHTML and CDATA? Encoding it as a sequence of randomly-spaced base64 snippets? Using character entities like `&#123` to encode non-representable byte values? Garnish with some HTML boilerplate that is discarded on the receiver's side and you should at least make it harder. That said, you should edit your question instead of commenting on it if you want to clarify something.

Comment: Haha you just made me realise I was thinking about doing this in such an overly complicated way. I was really worried about the possibility of corrupting my data, but your right, it should be quite easy to achieve enough obfuscation to fool a simple packet scanner. Thanks for the insight.